# Fill colours in shapebuilder tool not in the CS6 version?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, shapes, cs6

Im following a tutorial, I noticed using the shapebuilder tool there is an option in the version the tutor is using where you are able to also colour the shapes using the tool and seperate them with the fill colours. I can't seem to do that in my CS6 version I am wondering if Live paint is the alternative? Even then I can't seperate the shapes once filled like it was done in the tutorial.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's there in CS6.

You may need to tick the `Cursor Swatch Preview`. See below. 
To do that, **double-click** the tool in the tool bar or press the <kbd>**Return**</kbd> key when the tool is *active*.

[image]